# How to read $Q_j = \{k:\beta_k = j\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, quantifiers, logic-translation

In my work, I came across the following expression:

$$Q_j = \{k:\beta_k = j\},\tag1$$

where $j = \mathcal{J} = \{1,...,J\}$ set of cell-phone tower,

$k = \mathcal{K} = \{1,...,K\}$ is a set of users, and

$\beta_k$ is the index of cell-phone tower to whom user $k$ is associated with.

I understand that equation $(1)$ expresses a set but, how to read it in terms of set theory?

Comment: It's the set of users assigned to a given cell-phone tower, as nearly as I can tell

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir.....I know that $:$ denotes "such that". Could u please tell what $=$ to signifies in equation (1)

Comment: k such that the beta of k is j, where j is specified on the left side by the subscript j. Without subscripts, this is `Q(j) = {k: beta(k) = j}` which might be easier to understand

Comment: Ok...Once again thanks sir for detailed comment...

Comment: I think you meant to write $j \in \mathcal{J}$ and $k \in \mathcal{K}$ rather than equal signs. The set $\mathcal{J}$ contains all the (indices of the) cellphone towers, and $j$ is just one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. $j = \mathcal{J} = \{1,...,J\}$ set of cell-phone tower
> 2. $k = \mathcal{K} = \{1,...,K\}$ is the set of users
> 3. $\beta_k$ is the index of cell-phone tower to whom user $k$ is associated with
> 4. $Q_j = \{k:\beta_k = j\}.\tag1$

Correction:

1. $\mathcal{J}=\{j_1,...,j_J\}$ is a set of cellphone towers.
2. $\mathcal{K}=\{k_1,...,k_K\}$ is a set of cellphone users.
3. For each cellphone user $k,\;\beta_k$ is the cellphone tower that $k$ is associated with.
4. $\forall j\in\mathcal J,\quad Q_j = \{k\in\mathcal{K}:\beta_k = j\}.\tag1$

$\mathcal J$ is a set of $J$ cellphone towers; $\mathcal K$ is a set of $K$ cellphone users; $$\forall j\in\mathcal J,\quad Q_j = \{k\in\mathcal{K}:k\text{ is associated with }j\}.$$ That last clause reads: for each tower $j$ in $\mathcal{J},\,Q_j$ is the subset of $\mathcal K$ such that every user in $Q_j$ is associated with $j.$

Comment: Thank you so much sir for detailed comment.....:) :)